# Solve the formula for the indicated variable.

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I can't seem to understand how to solve for 'y' in this equation for my college algebra class. Please help.

Solve the formula for the indicated variable. (Enter your answers as a comma-separated list.)

$$x^2 - 5xy + y^2 = 0$$

Comment: One way would be to treat the above as a quadratic in the variable $y$ and treat $x$ constant, then use the quadratic formula.

Comment: $(x-\frac{5y}{2})^2=\frac{21y^2}{4}$ so...

Comment: This is an ordinary quadratic equation in $y$, use the standard formula.

Comment: Treat $x$ as constant and solve the quadratic in $y$.

Answer (score 1):

To solve for y.

I thought of the equation as a quadratic, treating $x$ as a constant:

$$x^2 − 5xy + y^2 = 0   \;   \iff  \;    y^2 - 5xy + x^2 = 0$$

After that, I plugged it into the quadratic formula to solve for $y$:

ANSWER: $$ \frac{5x + x \sqrt{21}}{2} , \frac{5x - x \sqrt{21}}{2} $$.

Comment: Thanks to Kevin and Mrs for the help!

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, noticing that the equation is homogeneous, divide by $x^2$ to get

$$\left(\frac yx\right)^2-5\frac yx+1=0$$

and

$$\frac yx=\frac{5\pm\sqrt{21}}2.$$